# How can you securely destroy data permanently and completely?

Tags: deletion, hard-drive

I have some extremely sensitive data on a computer, hard drive, and on a private server. I do not care about cost or method, as I have a lot of funds (though not unlimited) and I do *not* want to go through a third party data sanatization company. I also do not want to connect those things to internet because the time it is exposed will make it a target for mallard, Trojans, Spyware, etc. I need a wally that will completely destroy and delete the data. It should not be recoverable by any software or technology possible. I also would like a way that is more reliable and secure than physical destruction. That could work, if I hit it with nitroglycerin, throw it in acid, burn it, melt it, then spread the pieces around the world, but that would take a lot of time and I would like a quick way.

### What way will make all data irreversibly unrecoverable while leaving no evidence of it ever existing?

Comment: Somewhat. I don't know if that is secure enough for my purposes. I would need to really have a super high level of destruction to do it... and I'm not sure if it is 100% secure or why.

Answer (score 0):

Physically destroy the drive.

Smash it to bits, drill holes in it, cut it in up with an acetylene torch, melt it with thermite, whatever you fancy.

Comment: This works well, but it might now work well enough for me. I need the data to be irrecoverable completely, and there will still be traces of it existing (the slag, pieces, etc.

Comment: @Jeffjeff are you saying that you believe that an any data on magnetic or solid state drive can survive a 2500C thermite reaction? What are you basing that on?

Comment: The outer shell is solid tungsten carbide.

Comment: I'm not sure that I can do that without using high end weaponry, which is the one thing I can't get

Comment: @Jeffjeff you've got a hard drive inside a tungsten carbide case? That's...unusual. Either way, cut in in half and melt the bits.

Comment: How do I cut the case in half?

Comment: I know it's possible, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Got it. I will just bomb it to oblivion.

Comment: You may want to reconsider third parties, as they can provably destroy the disk you gave them and hand you the video record of the entire procedure.  I wouldn't trust a third party that takes the disks far, but one sitting in your parking lot or driveway isn't going anywhere with those disks in whole condition.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we are talking about a traditional spinning platter hard disk drive: unscrew the disk housing completely then score the surfaces of the platters as much as you want in both complete radial lines and also circles. Put them into a burning brazier when finished.

Of course you could do this instead of zeroing all the data but you can do the whole lot depending on how paranoid you are.

SSD? Remove memory chips from housing and blend.

Comment: Please refrain from using the word paranoid. Use something like privacy-oriented or privacy-minded, or how confidential your data is...

Comment: There would still be traces left of it existing. It's a good idea though.